# How to add providers in angular2 jasmine testing spec since addProvider is deprecated in RC6?

Tags: angularjs, angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I am trying to write my `beforeEach` like this so that every `it` gets the required modules / providers:

```
beforeEach(() => addProviders([
        BaseRequestOptions,
        MockBackend,
        {
            provide: Http,
            useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) => new Http(backend, options),
            deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        },
        MyService
    ]));
```

But since `addProviders` method is deprecated in RC6, what is a better alternative to add my providers?

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, I needed to add the below to get the tests working TestBed.compileComponents();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [TestBed](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html) from `@angular/core/testing` to create test modules. For example

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ ... ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    providers: [
      { .. },
      MyService
    ]
  });
});
```

It's pretty much the same as configuring a regular module except you don't need to export anything.

See more complete examples in the [ng2-test-seed](https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed). It has examples of testing components also using the `TestBed`

Comment: I do exactly this, but even though the service I'm testing is in the providers list, it tells me there's no provider for my service. :(